# regex to fetch mobile numbers with space from a php string

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex which will fetch all mobile numbers with the format `+91-9544xxxxxx`.

But in my PHP string, I may have numbers like `+91 9544x XXXXX` or `919544X XXXXX` or `9544-xxx-xxx`

How to fetch also these using regex?

```
+91 countrycode
Mobile numbers are 10 digit long : +91-9876543210
```

EX: if string contains 91 then and next 10 digits excluding whitespace are  digits, consider it as a number. or if string contains 95440 and followed by space and 5 numbers then it is also a mobile number. or if it is 9544-xxx-xxx this is also a number.

My regex `(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}`

I tried `(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d\s{9}` But I am not getting anything.

```
preg_match_all("/(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d\s{9}/", $words, $num);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `\d` as `[ -]*\d` if you want to optionally allow space or hyphen with the numbers. Also, escaping `-` is not necessary if it is present inside character set and as in one of your sample I see you want to allow only space instead of just hyphen, I am modifying your `[\-]` to `[ -]`. Also, you should use start/end `^` and `$` anchors to avoid match partially in a text and over you can use this regex,

```
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789](?:[ -]*\d){9}$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAyqiP/1)**

Comment: this is not working in php code `preg_match_all("/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789](?:[ -]*\d){9}$/", $words, $num);`

Comment: @VictorJohnzon: Can you add the sample and your code in your post? It should match as per my regex demo.

Comment: your regex is working in demo and it is best one . I removed the $ at the end so that it will only take numbers with 12 digit including country code and excluding white spaces.. But it is not working it `preg_match_all()`

Comment: If you want to remove `$` from the end, you can actually use `\b` at the end to match the word boundary.

Comment: can you pls explain the use of `\b`?

Comment: `\b` is called word boundary (aka zero length assertions) and matches the point where a word character meet a non-word character or vice-versa. Using `\b` ensures your input will not match partially if what you intend to match is further followed by some word characters and a word character is composed on alphanumeric and underscore. [Have a look at this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)